# A desktop program retrieving data from web?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a website that uses MySQL. Now I want to write a program in C++ that retrieves some 'secret' data from that website and do something with it. By 'secret' data I mean database statistics and some other stuff that visitors mustn't have access.

Now my question is, what is the best way to make this data available for a desktop program? I thought of doing something like this: Have an API that displays data, but a password must be passed throught GET or POST in order for this data to be displayed on the page, such as: mywebsite.com/api/somequery.php?password=mypassword. Then a desktop program would access this URL and get the data that is displayed in the page (if the password is correct, of course).

Is it a safe and acceptable way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've used that strategy (from a mobile app) and it's fine if the data isn't highly sensitive. Obviously this request can be snooped over a network, so it's far from perfect.

If it's worth the extra effort, you should use strong encryption, download the blob, and unencrypt it.

Comment: What do you mean by "this request can be snooped over a network"?

Comment: Someone can use something like Wireshark to look at the POST request and find out your secret key, then use it for themselves.

Comment: "snooped"?  Anything that goes in cleartext over the wire can be read by tapping the line in-transit.  SSL (and HTTPS) will eliminate this risk.  Google `tcpdump` and `wireshark`.

Comment: But for that it would require the hacker to be physically close to my machine, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. Wireless networks are by far the biggest culprit these days, but anywhere between point a an point b would do -- a virus on someones computer, someone at the ISP, etc. As I said, I found it acceptable for some uses, but it's not true security.